# QMdiArea containing QMdiSubWindows not visible to accessibility APIs

Tags: c++, windows, qt, accessibility

I am working with a Qt application and trying to implement UI automation through the accessibility interface. This all works well except for the fact that this application has a `QMdiArea` which contains `QMdiSubWindow`s and anything contained within these sub windows is completely opaque to the automation interface. I tried to inspect the elements through `UIAVerify` from the Windows SDK which shows the following:

[image: MDI area]

These subwindows contain a standard grid layout which contains standard Qt widgets. Since the heirachy here entirely consists of standard Qt widgets and all standard Qt widgets implement the accesibility interface as defined by MSAA I don't understand why all elements in the MDI area are hidden when I can freely access elements in all other areas of the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the reason is that `Qt` doesn't register its controls as valid `windows`. All controls in `Qt` are painted on one canvas. It is made for optimization reasons.

Such `Qt` controls are called [alien widgets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets).

Good news is that you can make `Qt` register all controls in Windows. The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets) states some ways to do that:

- Use the QT_USE_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 in your environment.
- Set the Qt::AA_NativeWindows attribute on your application. All widgets will be native widgets.
- Set the Qt::WA_NativeWindow attribute on widgets: The widget itself and all of its ancestors will become native (unless Qt::WA_DontCreateNativeAncestors is set).
- Call QWidget::winId to enforce a native window (this implies 3).
- Set the Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen attribute to enforce a native window (this implies 3).

The first one is the easiest and doesn't requiere recompilation of a program.

I tried it with `UIAVerify` and got a full tree of MDI controls.

Comment: Thanks, setting the environment variable was enough to get it working.   This does still seem like a bug though.